# Calculate nCr(n,m) mod k for large n efficiently

Tags: java, performance, dynamic-programming, number-theory

I need to calculate `nCr(n,m) % k` for large `n` (`n <= 10^7)` efficiently.

Here is my try:

```
int choose(int n, int m, int k) {
  if (n==m || m==0)
    return 1 % k;

  return (choose(n-1, m-1, k) + choose(n-1, m , k)) % k;
}
```

It calculates some amount of combinations mod k: `nCr(n,m) % k` by exploiting [pascals identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule).

This is too inefficient for large `n` (try `choose(100, 12, 223092870)`), I'm not sure if this can be speeded up by [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) or if some totally different number theoretic approach is necessary.

I need this to be executed efficiently for large numbers instantly which is why I'm not sure if memoization is the solution.

Note: `k` doesn't have to be a prime!

Comment: Didn't you just post this exact question minutes ago?

Comment: The previous one wasn't precise and it was explicitly asking about memoization which is not the case here, rather I'm asking for input to solve the more general problem of calculating `nPr(n,m) % k` efficiently (doesn't have to be memoization, it most likely won't be).

Comment: One thing that may save a bit on memory usage would be to externalize `k` as it doesn't mutate through the recursion.  This would save on memory because in your case you cannot take advantage of tail recursion.  So, every time it recurses, it retains all of the stack frames holding 3 **new** `int`s each time.  It holds these until it returns.  So effectively, externalizing `k` would remove ~1/3 of the memory usage.

Comment: @CraigR8806 good point, I'm more concerned about the runtime tho.

Comment: Runtime can be affected by memory usage.  If the stack frames are piling up, it can bog down the system.

Comment: http://fishi.devtail.io/weblog/2015/06/25/computing-large-binomial-coefficients-modulo-prime-non-prime/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes up now and then in programming competitions, one common way of solving this is using Lucas' and the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

@DAle posted a useful resource with the details: http://fishi.devtail.io/weblog/2015/06/25/computing-large-binomial-coefficients-modulo-prime-non-prime/

Answer (score 1):

Since nPr has an explicit formula `nPr(n, m) = n!/((n-m)!)` you should definitely try to use that instead. My tip would be:

- Remember that n! = n*(n-1)*...*2*1
- Notice that a *while loop* (yes, loop, not recursion ^^) could greatly optimize the calculation (the division cancels out lots of factors, leaving you with a multiplication `nPr(n, m) = n*(n-1)*...*(n-m+2)*(n-m+1)`)

Finally, you should calculate the modulo *after* calculating nPr(n, m), to avoid redundant modulo operations.

If it helps, you could try formulating a [loop invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant), which is pretty much a statement that should be true for all valid values of `n` and `m`.

Hope this helped :)

#### EDIT

I realized you said nCr after I wrote my answer. For nCr, you could add another while-loop after calculating nPr, that simply calculates `m!`, divide nPr by `m!`, and then modulo THAT answer instead. All in all, this would yield an O(n) algorithm, which is pretty scalable. It uses very little memory as well.

Comment: Sorry for the nPr and nCr thing, for your approach, it's too inefficient for large inputs. The chinese remainder theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement) is what I'm looking for I suspect. I'm currently trying to figure out how exactly I need to use it.

Comment: @AnnaVopureta how is the algorithm too inefficient? You can do all the cancellations before even starting to multiply. Then do the multiplications mod n.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I don't think the Chinese Remainder Theorem is something you can take advantage of here :) are you looking for an O(1) algorithm? The thing that costs is calculating n!. If you can find a way to calculate it in O(1), then the result will be O(1) as well. Otherwise, you would have to completely rethink this and scrap using the definition of nCr. Perhaps there is a mathematical theorem that fits your needs? Hope this helped :)

Comment: @Simon Sirak The problem is solvable by factorizing k, then solving the problem by substituting k for each of the found factors by applying Lucas's Theorem and then putting the results together by applying the CRT. DAle provided a more detailed description: http://fishi.devtail.io/weblog/2015/06/25/computing-large-binomial-coefficients-modulo-prime-non-prime/

Comment: @Henry Even after the cancellation, the multiplications get too expensive for large inputs.

Comment: @AnnaVopureta Ok, glad you could find a solution :)